# Start and stop multiple programs

Tags: batch, autohotkey

I want to start Spotify, [Toastify](https://toastify.codeplex.com/) and [EZblocker](https://github.com/Xeroday/Spotify-Ad-Blocker) at once, and exit them, if they are running at once.

Starting them is easy, just the start command, stopping isn't, I saw many answers on SO, but I don't know batch and I don't know how to do if else, it should be simple but I have never learnt batch. Plus I was wondering if autohotkey would be a better solution. I'm on windows 10.

Note that Toastify is able to start and stop Spotify, therefore I just need to start and stop EZblocker and Toastify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a .bat file that closes the apps on click?

Paste the following into notepad and save as a .bat file

```
set EXE=spotify.exe

FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto FOUND

start "" "PATH TO SPOTIFY.EXE"
start "" "PATH TO TOASTIFY.EXE"
start "" "PATH TO EZBLOCKER.EXE"
goto FIN
:FOUND

taskkill /IM spotify.exe
taskkill /IM toastify.exe
taskkill /IM ezblocker.exe

:FIN
```

- `set EXE` - Your executable file (spotify.exe etc.)
- `FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto FOUND` - check if EXE alias, spotify.exe, is running.
- `start "" "PATH TO SPOTIFY.EXE"` - Launch spotify and other apps if not running.
- `taskkill /IM spotify.exe`- Kill spotify and other apps if running.

Get the process name from the task manager and change the running .exe as applicable.

Where `/IM` will send the terminate signal to the application. However, for certain application such as Spotify, the application might simply minimize to the taskbar. Use `/F` to force close them in that case.

Comment: Could you add if else to your script to make it work like this: if no process (checking one of the 3 is enough) is running then start, else close which is what you did

Comment: Done. I tested with a single program only - but it should work if you tinker about it with, cheers.

Comment: Doesn't exit though, but works well,thanks so much